# How to write to XML using multiline string variables in VBA?

Tags: xml, vba, file-writing

I'm trying to write to an XML file in VBA with string variables that have multiple lines. The string is quite long, so I prefer to not break it up line-by-line, but can if this option doesn't work.

This essentially what my string looks like is the following:

```
myStr = "Today is Tuesday" & chrw(8232) & "Tomorrow is Wednesday"
```

I'm trying to write this to an XML file that will later be imported into a PDF. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
Dim fso as Object
Dim oFile as Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scriping.FileSystemObject")
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile("[Path]\myXML.xml")

With oFile
    .writeline "<myStrPlaceHolder>" & myStr & "</myStrPlaceHolder>"
End With

Set fso = Nothing
Set oFile = Nothing
```

Is there an easy way to fix it without breaking the string into multiple lines?

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/filesystemobject-object) for `FileSystemObject`? You're using `WriteLine`, have you tried `CreateTextFile` and streaming the content into it? FWIW XML doesn't care about line breaks, so you could also just `.WriteLine theEntireXmlContent` I think.

Comment: It's not really clear from the question what the core problem is.  As @MathieuGuindon notes XML does not care about whitespace, and if you prefer not to break it up line by line then don't break it up?

Answer (score 0):

**Write a string to XML allowing unicode characters**

Of course you can write the entire structure to an xml file and reserve it for later transformation via XMLT or any splitting action using XMLDOM methods.

A simple way would be to load your string directly via MSXML2 `.LoadXML` method into an XML object and to `.Save` it. Using a utf-8 declaration in the xml head allows you to write any unicode characters, too.

```
Sub String2XML()
'Author: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6460297/t-m
'[0]declarations
    Const Header As String = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>"
    Const myXMLFile As String = "myXML.xml"
    Dim myStr As String: myStr = "Today is Tuesday" & ChrW(8232) & "Tomorrow is Wednesday"

'[1]set late bound xml object to memory
    Dim xDoc As Object
    Set xDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.6.0")
'[2]write string to xml (utf-8)
    With xDoc
        .LoadXML Header & "<myStrPlaceHolder>" & myStr & "</myStrPlaceHolder>"
        .Save ThisWorkbook.Path & "\xml\" & myXMLFile    ' << change to your needs
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @KaraCombs Posted a simple approach how to write the whole xml structure including unicode :-) – did this meet your needs? If helpful feel free to accept by ticking the green check mark and/or upv.